# keyword/phrase density from a mysql database

Tags: php, lucene, sphinx, keyword

I have a LAMP setup, with the mysql database essentially being a catalog of products.  Since the database changes frequently as new products are added, it's cumbersome to manually maintain a list of keywords and popular phrases.  The need to keep a keyword/phrase list is twofold: (1) for google adwords and other marketing initiatives, and (2) for link structure on my site.

I've been using the Zend Lucene port as the backbone for all searching on my site.  Is it possible to do things like determine keyword density and/or phrase density using Lucene?  What about another search engine?

For further clarity of what I'm looking for, let's say I have a catalog of laptops.  I might have various models of Dell Inspiron, Dell Latitude, Macbook, Gateway, Lenovo, and Acer laptops.  For a keyword density report, I'd like to see that the words "laptop" and "notebook" are popular, as well as perhaps "Dell Inspiron" or "Dell Inspiron laptops" or "Lenovo laptops."

Can anyone recommend something to get started?  I'm sorta eying the whole search module world like Lucene, Sphinx, Solr, etc. since it's already indexing data, but I don't know if I'm going down the wrong path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene is capable of giving you a list of (keyword, frequency) pairs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667389/get-term-frequencies-in-lucene), or [this blog post](http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/searching-filtering-sect-freq-terms.html).

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this post is referring to pure Lucene (java), and I'm using the Lucene port bundled with Zend.  So hopefully I can do everything natively in php, otherwise I may need to scrub off the java cobwebs.

Comment: Seems like you can do this in PHP: search for termDocs() in this page: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.best-practice.html

Comment: I ended up writing my own script for determining keyword density, wasn't too hard with python.  I'll go ahead and accept this as the right answer...