# find the top words, relative to all documents

Tags: text, full-text-search, statistics, tf-idf

I have some 100.000+ text documents. I'd like to find a way to answer this (somewhat ambiguous) question:

**For a given subset of documents, what are the *n* most frequent words - related to the full set of documents?**

I'd like to present trends, eg. a word cloud showing something like "these are the topics that are especially hot in the given date range". (Yes, I know that this is an oversimplification: words != topics etc.)

It seems that I could possibly calculate something like [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf) values for all words in all documents, and then do some number crunching, but I don't want to reinvent any wheels here.

I'm planning on possibly using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for indexing the documents. Would they help me with this question - how? Or would you recommend some other tools in addition / instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_1_0/api/contrib-misc/org/apache/lucene/misc/HighFreqTerms.html

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667389/get-term-frequencies-in-lucene) also covers term frequencies in general with Lucene.

If you were not using Lucene already, the operation you are talking about is a classic introductory problem for Hadoop (the "word count" problem).

Comment: But can `HighFreqTerms` return stats for a subset of the whole index? (The same question goes for the Hadoop part.)

Comment: For hadoop, yes, because in your mapper you write simple filtering code that simply skips certain documents.  For Lucence, pass an instance of `org.apache.lucene.index.FilterIndexReader`.

Comment: I'm interested to try Lucene and `HighFreqTerms`, but I couldn't find any examples on actually *using* `FilterIndexReader` to filter the dataset. Any pointers?

Comment: I also didn't find any obvious examples on blogs, but [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=FilterIndexReader%20lang:%5Ejava$&type=cs) (beyond page 1) had some, as did going to amazon.com and looking at Lucence in Action and "search inside this book" gave results.  With Lucene, books are pretty helpful, IMHO.