# Frequency of a Term in a Document

Tags: java, lucene

I have indexed a set of text files by lucene. Also, I have stored TermVectors. But I want to know the frequency of some terms in some documents in O(1). Is it possible?

I mean, is there a **function(Term *term*, Integer *docNum*)** that returns the frequency of ***term*** in document ***docNum*** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get term frequencies in Lucene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667389/get-term-frequencies-in-lucene)

Answer (score 1):

There is no ready-made function, you'll have to write some code. First use IndexReader.termDocs(Term). That will give you a TermDocs instance which is, typically of Lucene, a Cursor-like object. Now call TermDocs.skipTo(int), then TermDocs.next(), then TermDocs.freq(). If you are sure at the outset that your document contains your term, this is it; otherwise check after each step whether you can proceed. The Javadocs are well-written for each step involved.